# How do I save a complete webpage displayed in Android's WebView?

Tags: android, webview, html

I am developing an Android application in which I have a WebView. I want to save the entire webpage loaded in this webview (Html + all resources + images + icons etc) into a folder and zip it and upload it to a server.

If you use WebView's [saveWebArchive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveWebArchive%28java.lang.String%29), then it is saved in archive format. How do I get the Html and images back from this archive? Is there any documentation for the format of this archive?

If I use addJavaScriptInterface to get the html as described [here](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/), I still have to copy the images and other resources from the webview cache dir (/data/data/your app package/cache/webviewCache/). However I did not find webview cache dir (/data/data/your app package/cache/webviewCache/) in Icecream Sandwich.

Is there a way to save the entire webpage displayed in webview along with resources in Android?

Thanks

Comment: Good question, I need to know this as well.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still interested, there is an open source project here that can read `WebView`'s archive format (saved with `saveWebArchive`) and display it back in a WebView.

https://github.com/gregko/WebArchiveReader

I couldn't find details of the actual format yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML 5 to store pages in the cache and load from the cache itself.

Caching is easy using HTML5, all you have to do is to make and refer a manifest file that holds information on what all elements need to be cached. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/).

And [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110624223059/http://alex.tapmania.org/2010/11/html5-cache-android-webview.html) is a good way to implement the cache feature in your web view.