# save cache of website in php for offline webview in android

Tags: php, android, caching, webview

I want to make a simple android application that uses webview for displaying a specific website. Since the app shouldn't open to no connection even in offline mode I want to save the cache first time and show it later. But using `myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);` this code only saves simple html files. The website i am using is in php. So it's not working, isn't there any way just the html part of the php page can be saved.

Comment: You can not save PHP Files within a cache. PHP files are processed on the server side and HTML files are processed on the client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the html to file storage and load it using iframe. If the app is in offline you can take the data from file storage. In this case your css and js have to be inlined to the page.

https://github.com/gregko/WebArchiveReader

[How do I save a complete webpage displayed in Android's WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021481/how-do-i-save-a-complete-webpage-displayed-in-androids-webview)